# Java query an ArrayList of predefined object

Tags: arraylist, java-8, collectors

I have an ArrayList (inputList) that parse this data:

```
id,name,quantity
1,foo,10
2,bar,20
3,foo,10
4,bar,10
5,qwerty,1
```

Code:

```
...
List<FooRow> inputList = new ArrayList<FooRow>();
inputList = br.lines().map(mapToFooRow).collect(Collectors.toList());
...

public class FooRow{
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Integer value;
}
```

I want to create a collectors that return me a list with the count of value grouped by name:

```
name,value
foo,20
bar,30
qwerty,1
```

How can I create a class Collectors to do this in the lambda expression?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`Collectors.summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```
Map<String, Integer> result =
    inputList.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 FooRow::getName, Collectors.summingInt(FooRow::getValue)));
```